# How to use php keep only specific file and remove others in directory?

Tags: php, unlink

How to use php keep only specific file and remove others in directory?

example:
`1/1.png, 1/2.jpeg, 1/5.png ...`

the file number, and file type is random like x.png or x.jpeg, but I have a string `2.jpeg` the file need to keep.

any suggestion how to do this??

Thanks for reply, now I coding like below but the unlink function seems not work delete anything.. do I need change some setting?  I'm using Mamp

UPDATE

```
// explode string <img src="u_img_p/5/x.png">
$content_p_img_arr = explode('u_img_p/', $content_p_img);
$content_p_img_arr_1 = explode('"', $content_p_img_arr[1]);    // get 5/2.png">
$content_p_img_arr_2 = explode('/', $content_p_img_arr_1[0]);    // get 5/2.png
print $content_p_img_arr_2[1];    // get 2.png   < the file need to keep

$dir = "u_img_p/".$id;  
if ($opendir = opendir($dir)){
    print $dir;
    while(($file = readdir($opendir))!= FALSE )
        if($file!="." && $file!= ".." && $file!= $content_p_img_arr_2[1]){
            unlink($file);
            print "unlink";
            print $file;
        }
    }
}
```

I change the code unlink path to folder, then it works!!

```
 unlink("u_img_p/".$id.'/'.$file);
```

Comment: If and when you do find a solution, **"I strongly suggest"** you be very careful with this, and **"make a backup"** of your entire Web site/folders, before executing such a script.

Comment: why?? it only delete flie in dir...   any reason why you suggest??

Comment: I'm "just saying", be careful that's all. ;-)

Comment: haha Thanks I thought it will happen some error then remove all website folder

Comment: Good stuff, take care and you're quite welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $dir = "your_folder_path";  
 if ($opendir = opendir($dir)){
    //read directory
     while(($file = readdir($opendir))!= FALSE ){
      if($file!="." && $file!= ".." && $file!= "2.jpg"){
       unlink($file);
      }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. but why the unlink() not work delete anything??

Comment: check permissions of your folder and also path to folder

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

This will get all files in a directory into an array, then you can run a foreach() on the array and look for patterns / matches on each file.

unlink() can be used to delete the file.

```
$dir = "/pathto/files/"
$exclude[] = "2.jpeg";
foreach(scandir($dir) as $file) {
 if (!in_array($file, $exclude)) {
  unlink("$dir/$file");
 }
}
```

Simple and to the point.  You can add multiple files to the `$exclude` array.

Comment: Thanks for reply. but the unlink() not work delete anything??

Comment: Don't forget to exclude `.` and `..` or do an `is_dir()` check.

Comment: @OP: Check that the user php is running under has permissions to delete the files.  Also, make sure the path is correct.  You could add an `echo $file;` under foreach to help debug.

Comment: @Jack:  Yes, I did this quickly, you could add . and .. to exclude[] or you could let it silently fail on those as unlink won't delete directories anyways.

Comment: The use of `@` should be avoided whenever possible, if that's what you meant by silently fail :) it's better to know what you're trying to delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_files( $folder_path , $aexcludefiles )
{
    if (is_dir($folder_path))
    {
        if ($dh = opendir($folder_path))
        {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
            {
                if( $file == '.' || $file == '..' )
                    continue ;

                if( in_array( $file , $aexcludefiles ) )
                    continue ;

                $file_path = $folder_path."/".$file ;
                if( is_link( $file_path ) )
                    continue ;

                unlink( $file_path ) ;
            }

            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
}


$aexcludefiles = array( "2.jpeg" )
remove_files( "1" , $aexcludefiles ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised people don't use [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) more. Here is another idea:

```
$dir = '/absolute/path/to/u_img_p/5/';
$exclude[] = $dir . 'u_img_p/5/2.jpg';

$filesToDelete = array_diff(glob($dir . '*.jpg'), $exclude);
array_map('unlink', $filesToDelete);
```

First, `glob()` returns an array of files based on the pattern provided to it. Next, `array_diff()` finds all the elements in the first array that aren't in the second. Finally, use `array_map()` with `unlink()` to delete all but the excluded file(s). Be sure to **use absolute paths***.

You could even make it into a helper function. Here's a start:

```
<?php
    /**
     * @param  string $path
     * @param  string $pattern
     * @param  array $exclude
     * @return bool
     */
    function deleteFiles($path, $pattern, $exclude = [])
    {
        $basePath = '/absolute/path/to/your/webroot/or/images/or/whatever/';
        $path = $basePath . trim($path, '/');
        if (is_dir($path)) { 
            array_map(
                'unlink', 
                array_diff(glob($path . '/' . $pattern, $exclude)
            );

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

- `unlink()` won't work unless the array of paths returned by `glob()` happen to be relative to where `unlink()` is called. Since `glob()` will return only what it matches, it's best to use the absolute path of the directory in which your files to delete/exclude are contained.See the docs and comments on how `glob()` matches and give it a play to see how it works.